# HUD Showing while performing segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the master-detail example on my app.

And I added the [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to show a loading screen while the detail get loaded.

The thing is that I dont know what am I doing wrong with the threads but I have ended up with 2 ways of doing it:

1 - If I do not throw the dispatch_async(), the HUD is showed with delay;

2 - If I perform the segue inside the dispatch_async(), it takes more time than necessary to load stuff.

Heres da code for example 1:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [HUD show:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:nil];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Heres da code for example 2:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [HUD show:YES];
    dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:nil];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that worked for me:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(openYourNewView) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    });
}

-(void)openYourNewView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourViewIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

However, I still have some weird rotation on previous view, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I‘ve managed a way around this somehow!

1. Create a normal method where you will call the progressHUD and call the second
2. Create the second method where you do the time consuming stuff (loading views)
3. Perform that method on the main thread

Sample:

```
-(void)callHUD {

            [progressHUD show];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [progressHUD dismiss];
    });
});
}

-(void)loadView {
    //Perform your segue or transition which needs to load
}
```

Hope that will help others looking for the answer. ;) Cheers