# MBProgressHUD is not working properly while performing segue (from MasterView to ModalView fullscreen)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a SplitView and when users touch a specific cell in the MasterView I need to show a ModalView full screen, insted to load data into the DetailView.
This ModalView is a huge TableView so I need to add a Spinner as feedback for users.
I've added a MBProgressHUD by calling a method in didSelectRow in MasterView but It doesn't appears immediatly; the app loads the huge table and then the HUD appears, but in that moment it's useless.
So, why it needs to wait the table loading before to appear?

This is my logic in pseudocode:

in MasterViewController

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==5) {
        HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController.view animated:YES];
        HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
        HUD.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        HUD.delegate = self;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyModalView" sender:self];
    }

     }
```

in MyModalView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // load all stuff related to table data
    [self removeHUD];
}
```

My question is very similar to that one
[HUD Showing while performing segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306319/hud-showing-while-performing-segue/18532648#18532648)
where I've added another partial solution,
but by using that suggestion I had a weird rotation if I use the app in landscape,
and also in portrait It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

in your view did load

```
 HUD=[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText=@"Wait...";
[self.view HUD];
[HUD setDelegate:self];
```

and use [HUD show:YES]; and [HUD hide:YES]; as and when needed

Comment: This is not the solution of what i need.
The problem is the load time. If you add the HUD to the destination controller your app freezes until the entire table is loaded, then you can see the modal with the HUD inside, but, again, useless.